# Thread.sleep() vs handler.postDelay() to execute network call in every 30sec

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I want perform a network call in every 30sec to push some metrics to Server. Currently I am doing it using thread.sleep(). I found some articles saying thread.sleep() has some drawbacks. I need to know am I doing it right? or Replacing the thread with Handler will improve my code?

```
public static void startSending(final Context con) {
    if (running) return;
    running = true;
    threadToSendUXMetrics = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(AugmedixConstants.glassLogsPushInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    mLogger.error(interrupt_exception + e.getMessage());
                }
                // to do to send each time, should have some sleep code
                if (AugmedixConstants.WEBAPP_URL.equals(AugmedixConstants.EMPTY_STRING)||!StatsNetworkChecker.checkIsConnected(con)) {
                    Utility.populateNetworkStat();
                    mLogger.error(may_be_provider_not_login_yet);
                } else
                    sendUXMetrics();

            } while (running);

            if (!uxMetricsQueue.isEmpty()) sendUXMetrics();

        }
    });
    threadToSendUXMetrics.start();
}
```

Comment: you want to send metrices if app is running or want to keep sending even app is not in foreground

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, My app is system launcher app and it remains on foreground. So, sending when app is running will also work for my case.

Comment: Why are you focusing thread then? A thread can be killed any time by OS. Why don't you try Android Service.

Comment: Thread.sleep is never ok on the main thread.  On a background thread like you're doing is perfectly ok

Comment: @AbdulWaheed A service can be killed at any time by the OS.  A thread can only be killed if the entire app is killed, or if you programmed the thread to be terminated when its owning Activity/Service is killed.  You have them backwards.  Although the two are not mutually exclusive (you can have a service with a thread)

Answer (score 2):

If You are using only one thread in the network, then usage of the `thread.sleep()` is fine. If there are multiple threads in synchronization, then the `thread.sleep()` command will block all the other threads that are currently running.
As per the details you've provided, there is only one thread present which isn't blocking any other active threads which are running in synchronization, so using `thread.sleep()` shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Handler.postDelayed` to schedule tasks if you are working in UI Thread and `Thread.sleep` if you are working in background thread.

Apparently you are sending some data using network, you must do it in the background thread, hence `Thread.sleep` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is:

- `Thread.sleep(millisSeconds)`: With this method, you only can call in background tasks, for example in `AsyncTask::doInBackground()`, you can call to delay actions after that. *RECOMMENDED CALL THIS METHOD IN BACKGROUND THREAD*.
- `Handler().postDelayed({METHOD}, millisSeconds)`: With this instance, `METHOD` will trigged after `millisSeconds` declared.

But, to easy handle life cycle of `Handler()`, you need to declare a `Handler()` instance, with a `Runnable` instance. For example, when your `Activity` has paused or you just no need call that method again, you can remove callback from `Handler()`. Below is example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Handler mHandler = Handler();

   public void onStart(...) {
      super.onStart(...)
      this.mHandler.postDelayed(this.foo, 1000)
   }

   public void onPaused(...) {
      this.mHandler.removeCallback(this.foo)
      super.onPaused(...)
   }

   private Runnable foo = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         // your code will call after 1 second when activity start
         // end remove callback when activity paused

         // continue call...
         mHandler.postDelayed(foo, 1000)
      }
   }

}
```

The code above just for reference, I type by hand because don't have IDE to write then copy paste.